# Excel Data Model Refreshing a Single Table via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, refresh, powerpivot

This is for anyone who may be looking to refresh a single table within the Power Pivot Data Model instead of the whole Model.

Why?
Well, when the excel workbook is opened, I wanted the users to only have a subset of data from the model visible, only their data. And updating the whole data model takes a long time.

So, instead of what I've seen where you place the following VBA code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Model.Refresh
```

You can single out one table and run this instead:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Model.ModelTables("data_tbl_Name").Refresh
```

where "data_tbl_Name" matches the name in your data model.

I hope this helps anyone out there.

Comment: You should split this into 2 separate pieces: (1) this question, as just the question, and (2) a separate answer - using the "post your answer" button. That way, people will more easily see that the question has an answer. You can accept your own answer, also. I think you have to wait 2 days before you can do that, if I recall.